# addEventListener not working for onDragStart

Tags: javascript, web, addeventlistener, event-listener

In my Javascript, I have the following code:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");  //Needs to be a, not div
a.draggable = true;
a.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event){drag(event)});
$("#id_of_main_page_in_html").append(a);

function drag(ev){debugger;}
```

When I run this code and attempt to drag this object, it should trigger the debugger, but nothing happens. I tried to run the same code using "click" instead of "dragstart" and it worked, that is when I clicked the object it triggered the function with the debugger, but dragstart won't work. Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome

Comment: @epascarello that's strange, I just tried it in Chrome too and it worked, the project I'm working on however needs to run in IE, I had to add what I mention below to get it to work there but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as usual, I finally get it working immediately after asking SO for help... I found that adding the line `a.href = "#";` before the addEventListener call fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
a.ondragstart = drag;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragstart.asp